# C++ const reference template function argument type is itself a reference, why?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, const-reference, pass-by-const-reference

I have the following function:

```
template<typename T>
void f(const T& val) {
    using value_type = T;
    using sub_type = typename value_type::sub_type;
    //etc...
}
```

However, I am running into the problem that the compiler is telling me that T is not fact whatever type it is, but instead a reference to it. How is that possible, in what circumstances are template parameter for const-references themselves references?

Note, I can work around the above issue with:

```
    using value_type = std::remove_reference_t<T>;
```

but I'd like to understand what circumstances T, itself, would be a reference.

Answer (score 3):

> How is that possible, in what circumstances are template parameter for const-references themselves references?

These things are independent. We have a template parameter, `T`. And then we a have a function parameter that happens to be `T const&`. But the two aren't tied together.

While `T` would never be *deduced* to a reference type based on that function parameter, deduction isn't the only way to provide template parameters:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void f(T const& val);

void g(int i) {
    f<int&>(i);
}
```

Here, I am explicitly providing `int&` as the template argument for `T`, it is not deduced. `T`, here, would be `int&` (not `int`) and indeed `val` isn't even a reference to `const` here, it would actually be an `int&` (not a `int const&`).

Of course the typical usage would be just `f(i)` (no explicit template arguments) which would deduce `T` as `int` and have `val` be of type `int const&`.

Comment: I'll check the callsites, but I don't think any of them explicitly specify the type. I get similar errors with both clang and gcc so I am quite sure it's my code that's wrong.

Comment: @111111 That's why we ask for [mcve] in [ask].

Comment: @Barry hard to guess what op problem was, but one common case when type is deduced to be reference is a when argument to function is universal/forwarding reference, possible that source in question is not properly reduced from real code...